How do I get the value of a cell within a for/next loop?
I need the value of a cell in a for next loop.  So far I have this:
'Sub getcellvalue()
Dim Man_Rows As Integer
Man_Rows = Sheets("Managers").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim Man_Name As Variant
Dim Man_cell As Variant
    
    For Each Man_cell In Sheets("Managers").Range("A1:A" & Man_Rows)
   
    Man_Name = Sheets("Managers").Range("A" & Man_cell).Value
    
    ' do stuff here
    
    Next Man_cell
End Sub'

I breaks on "Man_Name = Sheets("Managers").Range("A" & Man_cell).Value"
Please help
thanks

What [programming] language are you using? Is it Visual Basic?

@Abra Yes, it is VBA

I figured it out.
I replaced
Man_Name = Sheets("Managers").Range("A" & Man_cell).Value

with
Man_Name = Man_cell.Value

